# JasperReports: JRViewer causes exception to be added in container in JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

I have created a swing application. I have created a report with iReport 5.6.0. Now whenever I call the report and tried to add the report in JInternalFrame it throws exception. I am sharing my code bellow.

**Report Viewer**

```
public class MyReportViewer extends JInternalFrame {
    public MyReportViewer(String fileName){
        this(fileName, null);
    }

    public MyReportViewer(String fileName, HashMap parameter) {
        super("View Report",true,true,true,true);
        try {
            DB_Con db = new DB_Con();

            JasperPrint  print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileName,parameter,db.con);
            java.util.List list = print.getPages();

            if(!(list.isEmpty())) {
                JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);

                Container contentPane = super.getContentPane();
                contentPane.removeAll();
                contentPane.add(viewer);

                int sW =(int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
                int sH = (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()-50;

                setBounds(0,0,sW,sH);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            } else {
                BOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        BOptionPane.REPORT_MESSAGE,
                        BOptionPane.ERROR_TITLE,
                        BOptionPane.ERROR_ICON);
            }
        }catch(JRException jre){
            jre.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Frame**

```
public class frmMenu extends JFrame {
    public frmMenu(){
        initComponents();
    }

JDesktopPane dPane = new JDesktopPane();

//---- itemAllSizeInfo ----
                    itemAllSizeInfo.setText("All Size List");
                    itemAllSizeInfo.setFont(new Font("Rupali", Font.BOLD, 14));
                    itemAllSizeInfo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            MyReportViewer sizeInfo = new MyReportViewer(".\\Report\\All_Size_List.jasper");
                            dPane.add(sizeInfo);
                            sizeInfo.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
```

**The Exception:**

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$23.getRenderersCache(JRViewer.java:2256)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$23.getRenderersCache(JRViewer.java:2256)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$23.getRenderersCache(JRViewer.java:2256)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$23.getRenderersCache(JRViewer.java:2256)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$23.getRenderersCache(JRViewer.java:2256)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$23.getRenderersCache(JRViewer.java:2256)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$23.getRenderersCache(JRViewer.java:2256)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$23.getRenderersCache(JRViewer.java:2256)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$23.getRenderersCache(JRViewer.java:2256)

Can anyone help to find out to overcome the problem. ***I am using iReport 5.6.0 and JDK 1.7.0 version***

Comment: There is not enough info to reproduce, StackOverflow means your are looping endless inside a metodo, example the actionPerformed is triggered by the stuff you do inside it.

Comment: this report worked nicely before i compiled this report with iReport 5.6.0. the report was developed with iReport 1.XX version. so can you tell me what to do.

Comment: Its probably not the report but your java code.. try to put a some break points and/or logs in your methods. I can't test since I do not have all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/jasperreports/code/ci/6928c141f7bdd78ab96c1f8e68897f283be606af/) on the Jasper. Just use the last version.

Comment: I have been using 5.6.0 version. Which version should I use can you suggest me?

Comment: The stacktrace indicates that you are using JasperReports 6.2.2.  Upgrading to 6.3.0 (you can find it at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/6.3.0/) should fix the problem.